# Probability Question. Prove that P(A|B) = P(A) given that P(A|B)= 0.52 and P(B)= 0.43

Tags: probability

Hi all this is probably simple for some but i just can't get my head around it. I've been given the question:

Prove that P(A|B) = P(A) given that P(A|B)= 0.52 and P(B)= 0.43

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Do you know what it means for events to be independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a strangely formulated question, as it provides you with information that you do not need.

The definition of independence is $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$.
From the equation in your image, we have
$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A) \cdot P(B)}{P(B)} = P(A),$$
which only needs independence of $A$ and $B$,
and does not require knowledge any of the probabilities' actual values (besides $P(B)>0$).

---

Side note: Your problem asks you to show independence implies $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$. It is not hard to show the reverse implication holds. Thus $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$ is an equivalent definition of independence, and has an intuitive interpretation: knowledge or ignorance of event $B$ does not affect the probability of event $A$.